# How do I fix these touch events? Events respond if there are 2 fingers but not 1

Tags: javascript, canvas, mobile, html5-canvas

I am making a simple game of mine mobile-friendly.

The goal is to:

- Make character walk if a touchstart event is sensed on right half of screen.
- Stop character if a touchend event is sensed on the right half.
- Jump the character if a touchend event happens on the left half of the screen.

I have the logic working perfectly for mouse up and down events so I'm pretty sure it's something to do inside the touchstart and end functions.

If two fingers are used as one press it seems to work fine.

If only one finger is used it doesn't work properly: touching anywhere starts the movement but nothing will stop it.

Here is the code for the touch inputs and associated function:

```js
CheckWhichScreenHalf = function(e) {

    loc = WindowToCanvas(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    onScreenY = loc.y >= 0 && loc.y <= gameCanvas.height;
    leftSideX = loc.x >= 0 && loc.x < gameCanvas.width/2;
    rightSideX = loc.x > gameCanvas.width/2 && loc.x <= gameCanvas.width;
    if (onScreenY && leftSideX){
        return 'left';
    }
    else if (onScreenY && rightSideX){
        return 'right';
    }
    else return 'neither';
};

TouchMove = false;
TouchJump = false;

gameCanvas.ontouchstart = function(e){

    if (imagesHaveBeenLoaded) {
        e.preventDefault();
        for (var i = 0; i < e.touches.length; i++){
            var side = CheckWhichScreenHalf(e.touches.item(i));
            if (side === 'right'){
                TouchMove = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
gameCanvas.ontouchend = function(e){

    if (imagesHaveBeenLoaded) {
        e.preventDefault();
        for (var i = 0; i < e.touches.length; i++){
            var side = CheckWhichScreenHalf(e.touches.item(i));
            if (side === 'right'){
                TouchMove = false;
            }
            else if (side === 'left'){
                playerJumping = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The game can be played here: http://webstudentwork.com/jgossling/MMWD/mp2/mp2.html

Comment: The code works, the gameplay doesn't. This is because you try to assign two different actions on the same *one-time* event, i.e touchstart. So you will never be able to move and jump at the same time. One solution would be to listen to touchmove events, which will allow you to trigger both actions at the same time. But I am not a game-dev and can't tell it's a good design or not. An other approach would be to automate one of the actions (move) and leave the user control only the other one (jump), just like most runners do on mobile.

Comment: All in all, I wonder if this question wouldn't be a better fit to the sister SE site https://gamedev.stackexchange.com focusing more on this controls design than the code which once again is actually working.

Comment: thank you for your help I will post it there as well.